# InsertImage in document.execCommand not appearing

Tags: javascript

I made a function to insert an image through document.execcommand in JavaScript:

```
function images() {
    var img = prompt ("Enter the image link", "");
    if (img != null) {
    lol.document.execCommand("insertImage", false, img);
    }
    };
```

The image is not appearing, even on live server. It shows the broken image icon. This code is supported by all browsers. The rest of my execcommand functions are working well.

Comment: If its showing broken image icon, that means `execCommand` worked correctly, but with an incorrect image URL. Inspect the image thus inspected and check what its `src` attribute is. That should help you find the real problem.

Comment: well the image is a link.. i uploaded an image on a free hosting account... and grabed the link and paste in the prompt dialog box... it should work but in vain

Comment: ok. but what does it show when you do 'right-click -> inspect element' on that image?

Comment: The img tag for the crap image shows: <img src="http://www.freeimagehosting.net/auxqm">

Comment: Thats the problem. It should be `<img src="http://freeimagehosting.net/auxqm">` It is missing the **http://** part without which the browser will attempt to load it from your server itself instead of the image hosting server.

Comment: yes, but on Chrome inspect element it does show the HTTP, but still shows the broken image icon...

Comment: what is this 'lol' part before document in your code?